# Using dplyr to subset when criteria is that all variables names with a certain string pattern equals a value

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I am trying to subset all the rows from a dataframe, where all the variable names contain the string "race" and the variable itself equals the word "indeterminate":

```
import dplyr
a_race<-c('blue','purple','indeterminate','green')
b_race<-c('green','green','indeterminate','indeterminate')
c_race<-c('Texan','green','indeterminate','green')
team<-c('A','B','C','D')
df<-data.frame(cbind(a_race,b_race,c_race,team))
```

I tried:

```
df_new<-df %>%
select(vars(contains('race')) %>% filter_at(vars(contains('race')),any_vars(=='indeterminate')))
```

Which returned:
Error: unexpected '==' in:

```
"df_new<-df %>%
    select(vars(contains('race')) %>% filter_at(vars(contains('race')),any_vars(=="
```

I looked online and all the examples were numerical criteria, such as `any_vars(>3)`.

TIA.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter_at` as :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_at(vars(contains('race')),all_vars(. =='indeterminate'))
```

However, all the `_at` verbs are been deprecated, with `across` you can do :

```
df %>% filter(across(contains('race'), ~. == 'indeterminate'))

#         a_race        b_race        c_race team
#1 indeterminate indeterminate indeterminate    C
```

and in base R with `rowSums` :

```
cols <- grep('race', names(df))
df[rowSums(df[cols] != 'indeterminate') == 0, ]
```

Comment: Complete Answer. Can you please elaborate on the second code snippet. Any useful material to read into ~. usage in across

Comment: `~` is formula based syntax. It is similar to anonymous function. Some details in `?map`.

Comment: Thanks Ronak. For some reason my computer says it can't find the function across(). I made sure dplyr was installed. Maybe it's in dplyr2?

Comment: @NelsonChung `across` is present in `dplyr` 1.0.0 or above. Do `install.packages('dplyr')` to get the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can do

```
subset(df, !Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[grep('race', names(df))],
        `!=`, 'indeterminate')) ) 
#         a_race        b_race        c_race team
#3 indeterminate indeterminate indeterminate    C
```